# Is the complex conjugate of $|01 \rangle$ equal to $\langle 1 0|$ or $\langle 0 1|$?

Tags: quantum-information, notation

I can't seem to deduce this from the basic rules.

On the one hand, I think complex conjugation distributes of tensor products, so I would expect $|01 \rangle^* = (|0 \rangle |1 \rangle)^* = \langle 0| \langle 1| = \langle 01|$.

On the other hand, I think $\langle 10|01 \rangle = \langle 1 | \langle 0 | 0 \rangle 1 \rangle = \langle 1 | 1 \rangle = 1$, which should be the case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is entirely a notational issue, so the correct answer depends on your convention for denoting tensor products.  But the standard convention is the first case, where you *don't* reverse the ordering of the tensored states.  Under this convention, $\langle 10 | 01 \rangle = \langle 1 | 0 \rangle \times \langle 0 | 1 \rangle = 0 \times 0 = 0$.

Comment: The proposed notation (in which the order of the tensor factors is inverted) is actually quite nice... I don't immediately see any drawbacks.

Comment: @doetoe It breaks the expectation that <x|<y| = <xy|, which of course could (rather: would have to) be redefined, as anything else, but at a cost to elegance elsewhere. Also, multi-digit or multi-letter state identifiers would have to be excepted.